# Latex, left indent numcases

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, indentation

I have this simple equation (representation a dynamic programming recursion):

```
 \begin{numcases}
{Opt\left(P, i, \ell \right)=min }
\nonumber (1)\hspace{0.5 mm} Opt(P,i+1,\ell) + M(\ell,g)\label{eq:1}\hspace*{-10em} & \\
\nonumber (2)\hspace{0.5 mm} \min_{g \in L(v_{i+1})}\{Opt(P,i+1,g) + M(\ell,g)\}\label{eq:2}\hspace*{-5em} & \\
\end{numcases}
```

I have three questions:

1) How do I remove the equation number automatically added, I tried `\nonumber` but it didn't work.

2) More importantly, how do I control the left indent. Latex automatically centers the equations, but I am using a double column paper template and I would like the equation to be aligned to the left in this case, or at the very least control the left indent.

3) Is it possible in Latex to take any piece of latex code and rescale its output? For example I would like to place this exact equation but make it 90% of its original size.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: To left align to the page you can use the class option `[fleqn]` and then the left indent is controlled via `\mathindent`. See for exmaple [Left align (to the page) displayed math](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53773/left-align-to-the-page-displayed-math/).

Comment: Please don't mix questions; use separate questions.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer would have been self-evident have you provided an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). You must have something like the code below.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,fleqn]{article} % The fleqn option left aligns equations

\usepackage[outer=0.2in,inner=0.1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{cases}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{numcases}
{Opt\left(P, i, \ell \right)=min }
 (1)\hspace{0.5 mm} Opt(P,i+1,\ell) + M(\ell,g)\label{eq:1}\hspace*{-10em} & \nonumber\\ % Put the command \nonumber before \\ and do not put \\ after the last line in order not to create a new equation line.
 (2)\hspace{0.5 mm} \min_{g \in L(v_{i+1})}\{Opt(P,i+1,g) + M(\ell,g)\}\label{eq:2}\hspace*{-5em} & \nonumber
\end{numcases}


\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to use `fleqn` option to left align (not `rleqn`), and then adjust the indent. If you add the `showframe` option to the `geometry` package you will see that your MWE still produces an indented equation.

Comment: @PeterGrill, I have already edited my answer. I thought what I have written was the option `fleqn` as you can see in the code comment. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: One should ask *why* using `numcases` and suppressing the numbers; `cases` from `amsmath` is surely better.

Comment: @egreg Saw this post. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65060/controlling-numcases-horizontal-right-spacing-after-first-column Seems to me OP asked dup. Heiko also used cases there. But the question seems to indicate that there might be people out there who insist on using numcases.